# unable to use the variable in django

Tags: django

i recently started my django course online nad getting some problem.
i am not able to use my variable which i passed from index.html to about.html.
but in about.html it is not shown up.

.py file code :

```
from django .http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request , 'index.html')

def about(request):
    t1 = print(request.GET.get('text' , 'default'))
    return render(request , 'about.html' , t1)
```

index.html file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>template</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> hello everyone </h1>
<form action="/about" , method="get">
    <textarea name="text" style="margin: 0px; width: 1245px; height: 171px;"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="OK">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

about.html file code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>template</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>you typed {{t1}}</h1>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect `t1 = print(...)` to evaluate to? Note that `print` returns `None`. Further, the third argument to `render` should be either `None` (if not used) or a dictionary, e.g. `{'t1': "some data"}`.

Answer (score 1):

`print(..)` does *not* return anything. You can pass the variable to the context, for example:

```
def about(request):
    return render(
        request ,
        'about.html' ,
        {'t1': request.GET.get('text' , 'default')}
    )
```